# Multiple different layout alongside private route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create a structure with multiple different layouts alongside private route to show the correct content based on user's log in status and assigned layout. Currently I have 3 different layouts but I may add another one in the future.

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { LayoutOne, LayoutTwo, LayoutThree } from './layouts';
import RouteWithLayout from './components/RouteWithLayout/RouteWithLayout';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import Dash from './components/Dash/Dash';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound/NotFound';
import ErrorBoundary from './components/ErrorBoundary/ErrorBoundary';

const Routes = () => (
  <ErrorBoundary>
      <Switch>
          <RouteWithLayout
             component={Home}
             exact
             layout={LayoutOne}
             path="/"
             isPrivate={false}
          />
          <RouteWithLayout
             component={Dash}
             exact
             layout={LayoutTwo}
             path="/dash"
             isPrivate={true}
          />
          <RouteWithLayout
             component={Login}
             exact
             layout={LayoutThree}
             path="/login"
             isPrivate={false}
          />
          <Route component={NotFound}/>
      </Switch>
  </ErrorBoundary>
);

export default Routes;
```

RouteWithLayout.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { authService } from "./services/auth.service";

const RouteWithLayout = props => {

   const { layout: Layout, component: Component, private: isPrivate, ...rest } = props;
   const isLogged = authService.isLogged();

   return (
       <Route
       {...rest}
       render={matchProps =>
         isPrivate ? (
           isLogged ? (
             <Layout>
                <Component {...matchProps} />
             </Layout>
           ) : (
             <Redirect
               to={{
               pathname: "/login",
               state: { from: matchProps.location }
               }}
             />
           )
         ) : (
           <Layout>
              <Component {...matchProps} />
           </Layout>
         )
       }
      />
  )

};

export default RouteWithLayout;
```

please lmk I am doing this the correct way or I should take some other/better approach so simplify what I have been trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options to work with different Layouts.

The approach you have taken is good if you have multiple Routes that share a common Layout.

However if you have a lot of varying Layouts for different Routes, its better to actually render the `Layout` inside individual components directly like

```
const Dash = () =>  (
   <LayoutOne>
       {/* Dash component code */}
   </LayoutOne>
)
```

You could even adopt the above approach with common Routes too as its easier to use and let the Route component do what its actually doing.

P.S. Frameworks like Gatsby actually handle multiple layouts by using them within each Pages, so this is a good pattern to follow